# Criteria JPA 2 with 3 tables

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

I'm trying to create a criteria to retrieve some objects from 3 tables (Associate, Update and Detail). A Detail has reference to Associate and Update, and an Update has reference to a list of Details. My objective is to retrieve a list of Updates that has at least a Detail with null value in a specified field, given an Associate id. In JPQL was easy to do but the client said that this must be coded with criteria.

My JPQL was:

```
public List<Update> getUpdates(long associateId) {
    TypedQuery<Update> query = em.createQuery("select distinct u from Update u, Detail dt, Associate a "
        + "where dt.update = u and dt.associate = a and a.associateId = :id and "
        + "dt.ack_date is null", Update.class);
    query.setParameter("id", associateId);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I tried the following, but it just returned all updates in the database:

```
public List<Update> getUpdates(long associateId) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Update> query = builder.createQuery(Update.class);

    Root<Update> fromUpdates = query.from(Update.class);
    Root<Associate> fromAssociate = query.from(Associate.class);
    Root<Detail> fromDetail = query.from(Detail.class);

    Join<Detail, Associate> associateJoin = fromDetail.join("associate");
    Join<Detail, Update> updateJoin = fromDetail.join("update");

    TypedQuery<Update> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query

            .select(fromUpdates)
            .where(builder.and(
                    builder.equal(fromAssociate.get("associateId"), associateId),
                    builder.equal(fromDetail.get("associate"), associateJoin),
                    builder.equal(fromDetail.get("update"), updateJoin),
                    builder.isNull(fromDetail.get("ack_date"))
            ))

            .orderBy(builder.asc(fromUpdates.get("updateId")))
            .distinct(true)
    );

    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Can anyone help me? I searched but can't find any example with 3 entities.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Each join takes you from the leftish type parameter to the rightish one. So, the `details` join of my code (second line) starts from `fromUpdates`, that is a `Path<Update>`, and creates something which is behind the scenes also a `Path<Detail>`. From that, you can build other joins. Try this (code not tested):

```
Root<Update> fromUpdates = query.from(Update.class);
Join<Update, Detail> details = fromUpdates.join("details");
Join<Detail, Associate> associate = details.join("associate");
List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList();
conditions.add(builder.equal(associate.get("associateId"), associateId));
conditions.add(builder.isNull(details.get("ack_date")));

TypedQuery<Update> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query
        .select(fromUpdates)
        .where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[] {}))
        .orderBy(builder.asc(fromUpdates.get("updateId")))
        .distinct(true)
);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! These criteria joins made me crazy, but this helped a lot! Thank you perissf :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/870122/perissf Please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/72602473/8663316

Answer (score 9):

For three tables involved.

CriteriaBuilder builder = theEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query1 = builder.createQuery(BasicMemberInfo.class);

```
    Root<Table1> table1 = query1.from(Table1.class); 
    Root<Table2> table2 = query1.from(Table2.class);
    Root<Table3> table3 = query1.from(Table3.class);

   List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList();
    conditions.add(builder.equal(table3.get("Table1").get("memberId"), table1.get("memberId")));
    conditions.add(builder.equal(table2.get("tableid").get("memberId"), table1.get("memberId")));
    conditions.add(builder.equal(table2.get("indicator"), 'Y'));
    conditions.add(builder.equal(table3.get("StatusCd"), "YES"));

    TypedQuery<BasicCustInfo> typedQuery = theEntityManager.createQuery(
            query1.multiselect(table1.get("memberId"), table2.get("AcctId"))
            .where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[] {}))
    );

    List<BasicMemberInfo> custList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

public class BasicMemberInfo {

```
String memberId;
String AcctId;

public BasicCustInfo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public BasicMemberInfo( BigDecimal memberId,String AcctId ) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
    this.AcctId = AcctId;
}

public BigDecimal getmemberId() {
    return memberId;
}
public void setmemberId(BigDecimal memberId) {
    memberId = memberId;
}
public String getAcctId() {
    return AcctId;
}
public void setAcctId(String AcctId) {
    AcctId = AcctId;
}
```

}

Comment: Is the usage of multiple conditions like an sql statement with WHERE x=y AND a=b AND c=d .... 
Or do I have to use the "and(Predicate)" method to establish that?

Comment: it's like an SQL statement with Where clause.

Comment: `conditions.add(builder.equal(table3.get("Table1").get("memberId"), table1.get("memberId")));` It means Table3 class has member variable `Table1`? What if it has @OneToMany relation. And has List<Table1>, how we can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this test with even more than three tables . Also use static meta model instead of using direct attribute names.

```
    @Test
@Rollback(false)
@Transactional
public void   
fetch() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = 
entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Instructor> cq = 
cb.createQuery(Instructor.class);
    Root<Instructor> root = 
cq.from(Instructor.class);
    root.join(Instructor_.idProof);
    root.join(Instructor_.vehicles);
    Join<Instructor, Student> insStuJoin = 
root.join(Instructor_.students);
    insStuJoin.join(Student_.instructors);
    Join<Student, Vehicle> stuVehcileJoin.   
= insStuJoin.join(Student_.vehicles);
    Join<Vehicle, Document> 
vehicleDocumentJoin = 
stuVehcileJoin.join(Vehicle_.documents);

DataPrinters.
listDataPrinter.accept.   
(queryExecutor.fetchListForCriteriaQuery
      (cq.select(root).where
(cb.greaterThan(root.get(Instructor_.id), 2),                        
           cb.in(vehicleDocumentJoin.get
                          (Document_.name)).value("1")
.value("2").value("3")));
}
```