# Join two tables on multiple foreign keys using Criteria and Metamodel APIs

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria-api

Suppose we have the following five DB tables:
Employee, Client, Month, Onsite and Payment.

Given the following (Oracle) SQL query:

```
select * from onsite o
join client c on o.client_id = c.client_id
left join payment p on (o.client_id = p.client_id and o.employee_id = p.employee_id and o.month_cd = p.month_cd)
where p.payout_date is null and c.name = 'example';
```

It joins three tables. The first, inner join is simple, client_id is primary key in the Client table and foreign key in Onsite.
Supposing we have the EmployeeEntity_, ClientEntity_, MonthEntity_, OnsiteEntity_ and PaymentEntity_ metamodel classes, it looks like this with Criteria API:

```
EntityManager em = ...;
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<OnsiteEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(OnsiteEntity.class);
Root<OnsiteEntity> root = cq.from(OnsiteEntity.class);
Join<OnsiteEntity, ClientEntity> client = root.join(OnsiteEntity_.client);
```

Both the Onsite and Payment tables contain three foreign keys to the primary keys of the Employee, Client and Month tables.
The *left join* joins the Onsite and Payment tables on these three foreign keys.

The question is **how to express the left join of the two unconnected tables with the JPA Criteria API** using the metamodel classes?

Comment: I had a very similar problem, and this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46814689/10393763) provided the answer. Define multiple Root objects and join them in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JoinType.LEFT` as `join` parameter (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#JoinType)

```
root.join(OnsiteEntity_.client, JoinType.LEFT);
```

Comment: The question is how to express the left join of the two unrelated tables (Onsite, Payment) in Criteria API. Can you write a concrete example?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see it. Can you post code of your entities?