# How to create a query with parameter with criteria for generic class?

Tags: jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I want to create a query that will select all positions by the id of the smartphone with the `CriteriaBuilder` in the abstract facade

```
public List<T> findAllById(int id) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

[image: class diagram]

Comment: "positions", "id", "smartphone" are all undefined for potential readers. They know nothing about how they are related to one another. Unless you make things clearer, you will get only some guesses - not a full-worthy answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @HamzaElgarni Use Joins to relate `smartphone`, `position` and `message` See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17155157/599528) example